# how to click in apple scipt while in a app

Tags: applescript

ive been trying to figure this out for ages, and nothing is working.

i tried this first

```
set x to 866
set y to 600
    
do shell script " 

/usr/bin/python <<END

import sys
import time

from Quartz.CoreGraphics import * 

def mouseEvent(type, posx, posy):
          theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (posx,posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
          CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent)

def mousemove(posx,posy):
          mouseEvent(kCGEventMouseMoved, posx,posy);

def mouseclick(posx,posy):
          mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, posx,posy);
          mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseUp, posx,posy);

ourEvent = CGEventCreate(None); 

currentpos=CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);             # Save current mouse position

mouseclick(" & x & "," & y & ");

mousemove(int(currentpos.x),int(currentpos.y));      # Restore mouse position

END"
```

but that only clicked my mouse where it was and not at the designated coordinates.

next i tried

```
tell application "System Events"
  click at {123,456}
end tell
```

now this worked, but not in an application.

I tried doing this in roblox but this appeared,

```
window "Roblox" of application process "RobloxPlayer" of application "System Events"
```

and nothing happend.
please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is working"?   The posted script works for me in Big Sur.

Comment: im on catalina ;-; might work when i update to big sur ill see

Comment: Have you tried < tell application "System Events" to tell process "RobloxPlayer" to click at {123, 456} > (withOUT "end tell"s) ? Might work …